# Copy files under list of source directories to target directories using gradle

Tags: gradle, groovy, copy

I need to copy files under the list of directories to its corresponding directories in destination list. Say I have a list of source directories like `'A','B','C'` and a list of target directories like `'X','Y','Z'`. What I need to do is to copy files under A directory to be copied to X directory and from B to Y and C to Z. I have created a gradle task for this purpose. But I get an error

```
task copyDirs( ) {
  def targetDirList = ['/target1', '/target2', '/target3'].toArray()
  def sourceDirList = ['/source1', '/source2', '/source3'].toArray()

  [sourceDirList,targetDirList].transpose().each {
    copy{
        from it[0].toString()
        into it[1].toString()
    }
  }
}
```

And below is the exception I get when I try to execute it

```
 No signature of method: org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.CopySpecWrapper_Decorated.getAt() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Integer) values: [0]
 Possible solutions: getAt(java.lang.String), putAt(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object), wait(), grep(), getClass(), wait(long)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the `it` you're using is relating to the copy closure, not the values you're iterating through. Just name your element:

```
[sourceDirList,targetDirList].transpose().each { d ->
    copy{
        from d[0].toString()
        into d[1].toString()
    }
}
```